# How authenticate likes with no user registration at the end of 2022?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a potential customer, a restaurant, for which I would like customers to use a Qr Code to access a form to rate the dish they have eaten.
To make it as simple as possible to keep the user until the end of the notation, I am looking for a way to authenticate the user without going through the creation of a user space. In my eyes, I doubt the usefulness of the latter on the site of a small structure such as a neighborhood restaurant. He has not yet established his strategy for his web presence. At the moment, he just uses Instagram.
So I'm looking for a way to authenticate my user without their registration and at the same time certify their reviews and ratings.

I thought :

- to the mac address or phone number but it is a violation of privacy,
- the IP address: it can be dynamic,
- a cookie/localStorage: the user can refuse or delete it, and like again the dish.

I will use Nodejs, Reactjs and any database.

Comment: Where is the QR code located? Could there be one on each receipt, for example (that'd make things easy), or is there just a static one in the store on a sign somewhere?

Comment: Can you answer it? That'll determine what sort of solution is possible

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your comment.
You mean a QR code on each receipt might be unique and open the details of order ? In this way, customer can vote one time.
It's nice.

Comment: That's the most straightforward approach I can think of, but I imagine the main difficulty would be integrating it (communication with your API + printing custom image) into the restaurant's receipt printer, which may not be possible, depending on how it's designed

Comment: I will get in to check what kind of cash register they have.

Comment: Right away, I figured that in the QR code on the ticket, there would be a predefined id that the API could authenticate. 
The data in the QR code would also contain the names of the dishes consumed which would be integrated into a personalized form frame.